# Freezing objects transitively in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, immutability

## Example

Consider following program:

```
const engine = {"power": 200};
const car = {"brand": "Fiat", "motor": engine};
// Code using car object..
```

Assume that it doesn't make sense in my program to change values of car properties. Any attempt to do so would result in incorrect state of the program. I would like to freeze car object, which can be done by:

```
Object.freeze(car); // Make car immutable
```

## Issue

What would still be possible is to modify engine properties as engine is not freezed:

```
car.motor.power = 400 // Valid assigment.
```

When freezeing car I would like to also freeze engine and any references engine has.. etc.

## Question

**What is correct way of freezing objects transitively in JavaScript?** 
Is there any language feature / common way for doing that?